# Modifying an excel file with dropdown lists using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to modify an excel file using openpyxl.
The modifying part works, but after saving the changes all the dropdown lists/menus disappear. With dropdown lists/menus I mean that some columns have set options such as column A is for gender and has options Man or Woman. Is there a way to save the excel file with the included dropdown menus/lists in the correct columns?

I've tried to use ChatGPT but using data validation functions either gives me an error or still leave me with an excel file without these dropdown menus. Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this?

**edit**:
The code I used to modify certain cells is given below:

```
og_wb=load_workbook(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/Documents/B&B Post/Grondenlijst 2024.xlsx")
workbook=load_workbook(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/Documents/B&B Post/Grondenlijst 2024.xlsx")
worksheet=workbook['2023 Gronden - Pro forma']
# Find the correct row based on your condition
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=worksheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=worksheet.max_column):
    # Your code here
    
    if row[2].value == bsn:
        
        # Update the value in the desired column of the correct row
        worksheet.cell(row=row[0].row, column=6, value=kolom_F)  
        worksheet.cell(row=row[0].row, column=8, value=kolom_H)
        if row[4].value=='Stukken ontvangen?':
            worksheet.cell(row=row[0].row, column=5, value='Ontvangstbevestiging?')
```

And the code ChatGPT gave me to 'copy' these data validation cells is given by:

```
columns_with_validation = ['A', 'E', 'H']

                for column in columns_with_validation:
                    # Retrieve data validation settings for the column
                    for row in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
                        cell = worksheet[column + str(row)]
                        print(type(cell))
                        if hasattr(cell, 'data_validation') and cell.data_validation is not None:
                            # Create a new data validation object and copy settings
                            dv_copy = DataValidation(type=cell.data_validation.type)
                            dv_copy.formula1 = cell.data_validation.formula1
                            dv_copy.formula2 = cell.data_validation.formula2
                            dv_copy.showDropDown = cell.data_validation.showDropDown
                            dv_copy.errorTitle = cell.data_validation.errorTitle
                            dv_copy.error = cell.data_validation.error
                            dv_copy.errorStyle = cell.data_validation.errorStyle
                            dv_copy.promptTitle = cell.data_validation.promptTitle
                            dv_copy.prompt = cell.data_validation.prompt
                            dv_copy.promptStyle = cell.data_validation.promptStyle

                            # Apply data validation to the same cell in the new Excel file
                            worksheet.add_data_validation(dv_copy)
                            dv_copy.add(cell)
```

The problem however is that these cells do not have attribute data_validation

Comment: Could you paste some more details in your post to provide us a minimal code to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: You have a workbook with Sheet containing DataValidation applied by (Openpyxl or some other method?). Then open the workbook in Openpyxl, add some values to some cells per your example code, save the workbook and the DV no longer exists in the Sheet? Is your Openpyxl version the latest release?

Comment: @moken Exactly! When I save it, the columns that have those dropdown menus no longer have these menus. My openpyxl is indeed the latest version

Comment: Generally this would not be expected but has been seen before and appears to be due to how the lists are sourced. How is the DV created in your Sheet, manually or via Openpyxl or another method? What is the actual setup i.e. how is the list sourced, actual values in the source or reference to cells on the same/another Sheet?

Comment: @moken The excel file is kinda a data base for us so the DV has been added manually already. The source for the options for the dropdown list come from another sheet 'Source'

Comment: Looks like you may be running into a [OOXML issue](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1458) and are perhaps getting the warning message when reading the XLSX file *UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed* ? Your option would be to just re-apply the DV before saving. See the [Example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html?highlight=datavalidation#examples) on adding DV list with Openpyxl.